# Why are WSL GUI apps rendered with blurry fonts with Xming?

Tags: xorg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, anti-aliasing, cleartype, xming

When I try to use Xming with WSL to run GUI programs, I see fonts with grayscale anti-aliasing, like with Firefox as you can see here:

[image: Screenshot]

This happens with every distro I've tried (Arch and Ubuntu), and it makes me want to poke my eyes out, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to fix it.

*(**Note:** If you have a high DPI screen, the image will be blurry—you can press F12 and run this Javascript code to scale down: `document.body.style.zoom = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio`.)*

What is the cause of this problem? Is the problem with Xming or with the distro? I've tried following all of the advice on Xming's website to no avail.

Comment: Is that only for Arch? I didn't look so close before.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: You know, I had this problem on an older Ubuntu too (16.04 I think?), but now that I try it on the Ubuntu I just installed yesterday (18.04, testing via `xterm -fa 'Ubuntu Mono' -fs 12` like I had for Arch earlier) I don't seem to have this problem. Not sure what the reason might be.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: I figured it out -- it's because I'm using the same home directory which has the same `fonts.conf`. That's the fix on Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### (Updated to also address VSCode)

For ***some*** programs, the solution is to just add this to `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`:

```
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="antialias" mode="assign"><bool>true</bool></edit>
    <edit name="hinting" mode="assign"><bool>true</bool></edit>
    <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign"><const>hintfull</const></edit>   <!-- try hintmedium if it looks bad -->
    <edit name="lcdfilter" mode="assign"><const>lcddefault</const></edit>
    <edit name="rgba" mode="assign"><const>rgb</const></edit>             <!-- set to match your display -->
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

For these programs, after you do this, you should get nice, smooth rendering, like I did here:

[image: Screenshoot]

However, for other programs, such as for **Visual Studio Code** (which uses Electron), you need to also install `freetype2-cleartype`.
As Arch's manual [explains](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/font_configuration#Subpixel_rendering), the initial cause of the problem is Microsoft patents preventing subpixel rendering, and that, in order to fix this, `freetype2-cleartype` can be installed from AUR either manually, or via the following (**note** that I'm skipping signature checking here to make it work for me):

```
yaourt --m-arg "--skippgpcheck" -S --needed freetype2-cleartype
```

If you don't have `yaourt`, you'll want to [compile and install that](https://www.ostechnix.com/install-yaourt-arch-linux/) from [its AUR repo](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/package-query/), and if when doing that you get GPG errors and the usual `sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys` doesn't work, you'll want to run `sudo pacman-key --populate` as explained [here](//stackoverflow.com/a/45949102/541686).