# Blurry fonts on using Windows default scaling with WSL GUI applications (HiDPI)

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xming, vcxsrv

Is there a way to fix blurry fonts in linux GUI applications when being run from WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) using the default Windows scaling? Things I have tried so far:
With Xming:

1. Tried disabling Windows scaling and setting it from linux side using `GDK_DPI_SCALE=2.5`, the problem with this is several things like context menu icons don't play nicely and are often not scaled. Without `GDK_DPI_SCALE=2.5`, applications are basically unusable since the text is extremely tiny.
2. Tried installing all the fonts from C:\Windows\Fonts to `C:\Program Files\Xming\fonts\TTF` and running `mkfontscale`, couldn't make it work this way either.
3. Tried using VcXsrv, has the same issue.

### Screenshots

- Clion:

[image: Clion]

- Comparison between emacs (WSL) and VS Code (Windows native)

[image: Comparison between emacs (WSL) and VS Code (Windows native)]

All the resources I have looked up so far:

1. [Why are WSL GUI apps rendered with blurry fonts with Xming?](https://superuser.com/questions/1324140/why-are-wsl-gui-apps-rendered-with-blurry-fonts-with-xming): The answer here is specifically for just firefox and electron based applications.
2. [Gnome-Terminal blurry on Xming](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/686zxw/gnometerminal_blurry_on_xming/): Doesn't have anything helpful in particular either other than a suggestion to disable scaling and using something else than Xming.
3. [DPI issues running GUI programs on a 4K screen](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/77a5ni/dpi_issues_running_gui_programs_on_a_4k_screen/): Suggests using VcXsrv.

The main purpose of doing all this is to be able to run text editors(emacs)/IDE(Clion) from WSL. And, the reason I cannot install their windows equivalent is we develop only for linux.

Few system details:

#### Screen

4K (3840x2160) - 15.6"

#### OS

- **Windows**: Windows 10 Home v1803 Build: 17134.345
- **WSL**: Ubuntu 18.04 (`Linux username 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #345-Microsoft Wed Sep 19 17:47:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

Comment: @Biswapriyo I am not sure what you meant by desktop environment, but the only GUI applications I'm using are emacs and CLion, every other application is terminal based.

Comment: I didn't know you could full DE using WSL, however, I'm just running these two applications. 
Can you add it as an answer? It might worth a try.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** The following procedure may vary with the actual hardware in system. The settings may change in your setup.

First, enable high DPI settings for the X server executable. Close any running instance of that X server. Open the folder where you have installed the X Server e.g. VcxSrv, Xming, X410 etc. Here I choose `D:\MyFolder` and VcxSrv as example. Open that folder, right click on `vcxsrv.exe` for VcxSrv or `Xming.exe` for Xming. Choose Properties > Compatibility tab > Change high DPI settings > Enable Override high DPI scaling > change to 'Application' (or 'System Enhanced' option). Here is the screenshot looks like after changing the settings:

[image: Enable_Dpi_Awareness_vcxsrv]

Also do the above steps for `xlaunch.exe` file. This change will add the following registry values:

```ini
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"D:\\MyFolder\\xlaunch.exe"="~ HIGHDPIAWARE"
"D:\\MyFolder\\vcxsrv.exe"="~ HIGHDPIAWARE"
```

Next, override GTK+ settings for the X11 environment. [This Gnome article](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-x11.html) has in-depth view of the environment variables. `GDK_SCALE` will scale the windows by specific factor. `GDK_DPI_SCALE` will scale DPI for scale aware applications. Enable the settings with the following commands in bash (or other shell).

```bash
export GDK_SCALE=0.5
export GDK_DPI_SCALE=2
```

Change those value according to your system. Now execute the X server and the X11 programs. [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/7s3jav/on_high_resolution_monitor_x_apps_are_blurry/) also helps.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Just to be sure I verified it with firefox too. Seems like I missed the `GDK_SCALE` flag. One thing that didn't work was Clion (however manually changing the font to 2.5 times the original fixed it). The rendering is quite slow though, particularly in case of firefox but that's for another question.

Comment: @lol BTW, the include guard in header file shouldn't start with underscore (in VScode image).

Comment: you are correct, but this from an academic project where people didn't bother for such things.

Comment: Please note that you don't need to change anything in Linux if your problem is just the blurriness and you don't mind if the gui is very small.

Comment: You may also use `gnome-tweaks` to adjust the font size. (`gnome-tweaks` is a small utility that you can install via `apt` and that let's you customize WSL gui windows.)